# Fast producer, slow consumer. Disk I/O

Tags: java, android, multithreading, io

I am trying to store data from various Android sensors into a csv file.

So, to accept the sensor data from Android api, one has to implement the following method.

```java
BlockingQueue<SensorEvent> dataQueue;

// Producer: runs on a HandlerThread
@Override
public void onSensorEvent(SensorEvent event) {
    dataQueue.put(event);
}
```

Now, I save this data to a file using apache commons-csv api.

```java
CSVPrinter csvPrinter;

// Consumer: runs on a simple java Thread
@Override
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        SensorEvent event = dataQueue.take();
        csvPrinter.printRecord(event.values); // writes float,float,float
        // ... break;
    }
}
```

There are different rates at which sensor can provide the data, the fastest one is generating data every 4 ms for one sensor. This starts accumulating a lot of data in the queue if I am listening on multiple sensors. The consumer is doing a write (I/O) operation and hence it is slower than the producer. I am aware of the solution where increasing the number of consumers solves the problem. So, if I increase the number of consumers in this case, there will two threads writing data in two files.

**Que:** So, my question is it a good idea to write two files in parallel? Will it be really concurrent? Or, disk operations are inherently sequential? Can someone shed some light on this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: are you sure that `csvPrinter.printRecord(event.values)` writes data to a file immediately? Or you need to call something to confirm it?

Comment: Yeah, I am pretty sure it writes data to the file immediately, or rather writes to the disk cache, depends on the hardware.

Comment: No it isn't a good idea. The disk isn't multithreaded. You will probably only make it worse if you are already disk I/O-bound.

Comment: @chandr3sh Do you really need to write values to disk immediately? Can you store the sensor values in a csv object in-memory and write it to disk occasionally say once every 1 second? (e.g., append all the values sensed in the last second to the file), That should reduce the disk IO.

Comment: @VinayEmani How would it reduce disk IO? If I hold onto the data in a buffer, I will be just increasing the number of bytes to write. What is the difference b/w writing 1 byte every ms and writing 100 bytes every second?

Comment: It doesn't reduce disk I/O, it reduces the *time.* The difference is that a lot of write time is really latency, waiting for the right part of the track to arrive under the head. Once you're there, writing a lot of data doesn't take significantly more time than writing a little, and it saves all the extra seek latencies. Make sure there is a `BufferedWriter` or `BufferedOutputStream` under the CSV writer in your stream stack. You're also saving on context-switching time into and out of the kernel for each system call.

Comment: @chandr3sh You're not reducing the size of data to write, but the no. of write calls. Each write call incurs an overhead (e.g., seeking to the correct position to write). By reducing the # of calls, you'll be reducing this overhead.

Comment: @user207421 Yes, I have a BufferedWriter in there. Can you tell if buffering helps in case of SSDs?

Comment: It always helps.